# Joining 2 Table based from each id on table 1

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Let's say.. I have 2 table like this

**Table 1**

[image: table_1]

**Table 2**

[image: table_2]

I want to join 2 table above. Display each content from column **name_tb1** on **Table 1** and get the output of total/num rows from **name_tb2** on **Table 2** based from each of **id_tb1**

**Example Output:**

```
First (3 Row)
Second (2 Row)
Third (3 Row)
```

Comment: This is a pretty basic join / group by operation.  Have you made any attempt at a solution?  Can you show what you tried, and why the results aren't what you expected?

Comment: I know how to join 2 tables, but i don't have any clue for the case like this, so i don't have try it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT
    table_1.id_tb1, 
    count(*) 
FROM
    table_1, 
    table_2 
WHERE 
    table_1.id_tb1 = table_2.id_tb1 
GROUP BY 
    table_1.id_tb1
```

ON a sidenote, not thrilled by your naming convention and image. We like to help but copy and paste makes all easier. From a image we can't copy/paste text.

For naming call the PRI-KEY of a table 'id', and prefix the foreign key with the table name.

SO:

- table1.id
- table1.name
- table2.id
- table2.table1_id
- table2.name